# Are there any affordable host services for apple push notifications?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

The host would need to have port 2195 open and support push notifications under apns.  I have had some trouble finding a hosting service that would support this.

Also, it would be nice if you could have PHP, MySQL, etc. access under the same provider.

Comment: This probably would be better suited to ServerFault.com instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, the corresponding question is here:
http://serverfault.com/questions/49035/are-there-any-affordable-host-services-for-apple-push-notifications

But, I have yet to get any answers from there, so I will keep the question open for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look into http://urbanairship.com/push/ where they offer a hosted solution.

Comment: Looks like a promising service and I like the fact that you get 5,000 pushes per month free.  Although, the next pricing tier for greater than 5,000 pushes gets a little expensive at 30 bucks a month.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I Recently Used the Hosting from [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com/) (**Shared Hosting)** , They have the port 2195 open and support push notifications under apns. Its working for me, may be others can get some help too.

Answer (score 0):

There are other alternatives: I try to keep a up to date list on [my blog](http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/08/07/apple-push-notification-service-gateways/).

Stephan

Comment: Your blog returns a 404 for me?